# remove jquery validation class

Tags: jquery, validation

From the example below how can I remove the 2nd class using jquery?

From this:

```
<input type="text" class="span {validate:{required:true, messages:{required:'Please enter name'}}}" id="lname" name="lname">
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" class="span" id="lname" name="lname">
```

NOTE:

1. Element can have several classes
2. `{validate: ...}` is created dynamically

Comment: Why you don't use a `data` attribute for this information? like `<input type="text" class="span" data-validation="{validate:{required:true, messages:{required:'Please enter name'}}}" id="lname" name="lname">`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep the "span" class, you could do something like:

```
$('.span').attr('class', 'span')
```

If you want to remove the second class, whatever its name is, you could do something like:

```
$('.span').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', $(this).attr('class').replace(/^(.+?) [^ ]+/, '$1'))
});
```

Note that a class name cannot have spaces in it, therefore the second class should be the class following the first space and ending either at the next space or the end of the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.span').removeClass('{validate:{required:true, messages:{required:'Please enter name'}}}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally you would do this..

```
$("#element").removeClass("nameOfClass");
```

But this is some strange class, you've got there..

Answer (score 0):

Use remove class

```
$('input, select, textarea', '#form_id').removeClass('errorClass');
```